# JavaScript get array of values of field corresponding to each value in set of another field

Tags: javascript, arrays, set, grouping, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects like

```
const data = [
  {'name': 'apple', 'type': 'fruit', 'quantity': 5},
  {'name': 'orange', 'type': 'fruit', 'quantity': 8},
  {'name': 'broccoli', 'type': 'vegetable', 'quantity': 5},
  ...
]
```

For each unique value of `type` I need to return an array like

```
output = [
  {
    'field': 'fruit', 
    'count': 2,
    'minQuantity': 5,
    'maxQuantity': 8,
    'values': ['apple', 'orange'] 
  },
  {
    'field': 'vegetable',
    'count': 1,
    'minQuantity': 5,
    'maxQuantity': 5,
    'values': ['broccoli']
  }
]
```

Is there a simple/efficient way to do this?

What I've tried so far:

```
let returnData = [];
let fieldSet = new Set(data.map(a => a.type));
let fields = Array.from(fieldSet);
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
  let objs = data.filter(obj => {
    return obj.type === fields[i]
  })
  returnData.push({
    field: fields[i],
    count: objs.length
  })
}
```

Comment: There surely is a way to do this. Did you try using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Amazing the difference in tenor between some folks on the internet. Updated to include what I've done so far @AmirSaleem

Comment: Perfect @OJT much appereciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group data by type first using `Array.prototype.reduce`, and then usin `Object.entries` and `Array.prototype.map` you can transform the object into an array.

```js
const data = [
  {'name': 'apple', 'type': 'fruit', 'quantity': 5},
  {'name': 'orange', 'type': 'fruit', 'quantity': 8},
  {'name': 'broccoli', 'type': 'vegetable', 'quantity': 5},
];

const EMPTY_GROUP = {
  minQuantity: Infinity,
  maxQuantity: -Infinity,
  count: 0,
  values: []
};

const dataGroupedByType = data.reduce((result, item) => {
  const { name, type, quantity } = item;
  result[type] = result[type] || EMPTY_GROUP;
  const group = result[type];
  result[type] = {
    minQuantity: Math.min(group.minQuantity, quantity),
    maxQuantity: Math.max(group.maxQuantity, quantity),
    count: group.count + 1,
    values: [...group.values, name]
  };
  return result;
}, {});

const result = Object.entries(dataGroupedByType).map(([type, group]) => ({
  field: type,
  ...group
}));

console.log(result);
```